# How to create dynamic grid and corresponding buttons in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a page using bootstrap grid that has 4 columns when large, 3 columns when medium , 2 columns when small and 1 column when extra small. And also buttons at the top, large button when clicked changes the resolution to large, medium button when clicked changes the resolution to medium and small button when clicked changes the resolution to small. How to do that. Please help.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Grid</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href ="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" style="background-color:lavender;">
        <h1 style="text-align:center;color:brown">Lorem Ipsum Grid</h1>
        <br><br>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-2 col-xs-1">
                <p>
               // text
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-2 col-xs-1">
                <p>   // text
              </p>
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-3  col-md-4  col-sm-2  col-xs-1">
               <p>
                      // text
               </p>
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-3  col-md-4  col-sm-2  col-xs-1">
               <p>
                      // text
               </p>

            </div>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div  class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3  col-md-4  col-sm-2  col-xs-1">
                <p>
                    // text


                </p>

            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3  col-md-4  col-sm-2  col-xs-1">
               <p>
                   // text


               </p>
             </div>
             <div class="col-lg-3  col-md-4  col-sm-2  col-xs-1">
                 <p>
                       // text
                 </p>
             </div>
             <div class="col-lg-3  col-md-4  col-sm-2  col-xs-1">
                 <p>
                       // text                     </p>
             </div>
             </div>
             <br><br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3  col-md-4  col-sm-2  col-xs-1">
            <p>
                    // text
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3  col-md-4  col-sm-2  col-xs-1">
            <p>
                    // text

            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3  col-md-4  col-sm-2  col-xs-1">
            <p>
                    // text 
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3  col-md-4  col-sm-2  col-xs-1">
            <p>
                    // text
            </p>
        </div>

        </div>
    </div>

   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">  Would be the way to go, I believe. Hope it help you:)

Comment: thanks. and how to display the buttons for resolution when large/medium/small

Comment: do you mean the size of the font changes, or the bootstrap columns change?

Comment: when i click on the buttons, say small size , then i get small sized screen. the columns change. i could so far create only this :<button type="button"  class="btn btn-success  ">Small size</button>

Comment: I posted somthing below, hope it helps, if not I can edit it.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery maybe? Hope this is what you mean by changing the columns. Hope it helps you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </head>
<body>

    <div class="container" style="background-color:lavender;">
        <h1 style="text-align:center;color:brown">Lorem Ipsum Grid</h1>
        <button type="button" id="btn-small" class="btn btn-success ">Small size</button>
        <button type="button" id="btn-medium" class="btn btn-success ">Medium size</button>
        <button type="button" id="btn-large" class="btn btn-success ">Large size</button>
        <br><br>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-change col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <p>
               // text
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-change col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <p>   // text
              </p>
           </div>
           <div class="col-change col-lg-3  col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
               <p>
                      // text
               </p>
           </div>
           <div class="col-change col-lg-3  col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
               <p>
                      // text
               </p>

            </div>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div  class="row">
            <div class="col-change col-lg-3  col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <p>
                    // text


                </p>

            </div>

            <div class="col-change col-lg-3  col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
               <p>
                   // text


               </p>
             </div>
             <div class="col-change col-lg-3  col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                 <p>
                       // text
                 </p>
             </div>
             <div class="col-change col-lg-3  col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                 <p>
                       // text                     </p>
             </div>
             </div>
             <br><br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-change col-lg-3  col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <p>
                    // text
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-change col-lg-3  col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <p>
                    // text

            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-change col-lg-3  col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <p>
                    // text 
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-change col-lg-3  col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <p>
                    // text
            </p>
        </div>

        </div>
    </div>



    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script>
        $('#btn-small').click(function(){
            console.log('click');
            $('.row .col-change').each(function(){
                $(this).attr("class", "col-change col-xs-12 col-lg-12");

            });
        });
        $('#btn-medium').click(function(){
            console.log('click');
            $('.row .col-change').each(function(){
                $(this).attr("class", "col-change col-xs-4 col-lg-4");

            });
        });
        $('#btn-large').click(function(){
            console.log('click');
            $('.row .col-change').each(function(){
                $(this).attr("class", "col-change col-xs-3 col-lg-3");

            });
        });
    </script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i also tried using resizeTo() and resizeBy() functions. But the posts when i searched in here say that chrome,firefox and IE8 donot support resizing the window,for that i need to create a window by window.open()  .Your answer is also not working.I tried it like this - $('#extrasmall').click(function () {

            window.resizeBy(300, 300);
        }); - its also not working

Comment: I see, when I got time I look into it, sorry answer was wrong.

Comment: i read about it and Chrome blocks that feature. Don't know how to 'hack' it.